# How to read yml file present in docker using angular 7 at runtime

Tags: angular

I am new to angular, kubernetes and docker,
we have requirement of using .yml containing secrets.
we are currently putting every thing in environment.prod.ts file but looking to use .yml which will be present in docker (generated manually initially).

What I was thinking to use is 
Angular7+ --> environment.prod.ts (Put environment variables and get details of env variables (path of files) at build/run time from docker file)--> dockerfile (contains environment variables & path mappings of secrets files) -->  .yml file with secrets (get data from it at run time)

I have done lots of searching over it but could not find any thing to go with. Does anyone know where to find references to achieve it via code & configurations?

If there is better way of doing it, you are most welcome.
Please suggest.

Update: 
My requirement is to use .yml present outside of POD/built image but inside docker.
Instead of putting everything in Environment.ts/Environment.prod.ts, 
I am looking to put the same in .yml and use it at runtime(encryption applies)
Angular environment files will have only minimal information to execute above. 
Already tried 
1)reading Env variables in dockerfile using webpack
2) config file present inside build itself.

Does this approach requires http calls using nodejs? If yes please suggest.
Hope this clears the cloud instead of adding it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, whether I understand you correctly.
As you might know, you should never put secrets, that you do not want publicly known, into your frontend code.

As for using environment variables in your Angular app; You could use [angular-server-side-configuration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-server-side-configuration). Version 8.0.0 is intended to be used with Angular 8, as it makes use of Angular schematics and builders. Version 2.0.0 can be used with older Angular versions.

Disclaimer: I am the author of angular-server-side-configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the file to your assets in the `angular.json` file and have Webpack take it with you. You can then make a regular call to the file in a service to parse and use its data.

That's basically what the `environment.ts` file does too, it's being replaced in the build step as you can see in the `angular.json`.

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "src": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "replaceWith": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                },
            }
}
```

Same principle works for your own files :-).

Comment: thanks Bjorn, we are already doing it. I do not want to do it.  My requirement is to use file present in docker i.e. get data from yml present in docker from angular project.

Comment: You are already doing it and you don't want to do it? What is it? This is your option provided by the framework. Either rewrite your question and show what you've tried or what you're doing now, or accept the answer?

Comment: Yes, doing it currently and looking to use yml files. I have already mentioned it in que regarding putting every thing in  environment files  and planning to move away. my requirement is to use yml file present in docker. Your response is to use different env files for different images at build time. I am sorry can't accept your answer. Thanks